# Aws xray integration with lambda and kinesis integration

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis, aws-xray

I have a system that pushes messages to a kinesis stream. After that, a lambda consumes this stream and sends the wanted message to another lambda, I enabled aws x-ray in the second lambda. Still, I found that lambda doesn't sample most of the messages, i.e put the x-ray trace header 'sampled' with false. so I can not trace the request.

Is there any way to tell the lambda to trace all requests or any workaround?

github issue: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-node/issues/567

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda has a fixed sampling rate for traces and it cannot be modified: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-xray.html

"X-Ray doesn't trace all requests to your application. X-Ray applies a sampling algorithm to ensure that tracing is efficient, while still providing a representative sample of all requests. The sampling rate is 1 request per second and 5 percent of additional requests."

Comment: I know this already, so I added another and extra lambda that filter only events I am interested in to minimize the number of message, and this lambda call another lambda(2), unfortunately the second lambda also get sampled always with false !!